# What are the distances between Arduino Mega connectors?

Tags: arduino-mega

I am trying to build an Arduino Mega shield. For that, I need to know the exact distances between the different connectors.

Comment: Why not start with an EDA file that already contains the connectors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pin layout and dimensions of the Mega are as follows:
[image: Mega Board layout.]

Dimensions are in thousandths of an inch. [Source](https://blog.arduino.cc/2011/01/05/nice-drawings-of-the-arduino-uno-and-mega-2560/)